# Software for creating Email Templates

Tags: email, templates

I want to create good looking **Email Templates**  for my client. I used mailchimp.com and Campaigner  websites but i am not satisfied with that. Have any windows software for available to do this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Software suggestions are typically off topic for SO, so don't be surprised if this question gets closed on you.

However, for customized templates, you will need to know html as it pertains to email. If you need something outside of the templates supplied by Mailchimp or Campaign Monitor for example, you will have to either develop them yourself, hire someone or adapt one of the many other template resources available online.

There is no desktop application that has the same wysiwyg type template editor or intuitive drag and drop functionality features as Mailchimp. I guess it is just not a good business model these days to create downloadable software when you can easily charge a subscription instead.

What do you find inadequate? Is it the website functionality/features, the customization or the template designs themselves?